# SQL Query tuning - MS SQL Server -2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am new to sql tuning. I have the following SQL which takes around 15 to 20 seconds to produce the results.

```
SELECT D.DealerName,
       Z.Zone,
       C.Id                             ,
       L.Id                             ,
       A.Id                             ,
       L.LeadDate,
       LT.LeadType                      ,
       EM.FirstName + ' ' + EM.LastName ,
       LS.LeadSource                    ,
       --C.*,
       E.Id                             ,
       E.StartDateTime,
       0                                ,
       Chiefed = CASE A.AppointmentTypeId
                   WHEN 3 THEN 'True'
                   ELSE ''
                 END,
       9                                AS WorkflowPhase
FROM   Customers C( NOLOCK )
       INNER JOIN Dealers D
               ON C.DEALERId = D.Id
       INNER JOIN Leads L( NOLOCK )
               ON L.CustomerId = C.Id
       INNER JOIN Appointments A( NOLOCK )
               ON A.LeadId = L.Id
                  AND ( NOT( A.AppointmentTypeId = 5
                              OR A.AppointmentTypeId = 6 ) )
       JOIN CalendarEvents E( NOLOCK )
         ON E.TableId = 1
            AND E.TableRowId = A.Id
            AND E.IsDeleted = 0

            AND Dateadd(hh, @TZO, Getdate()) >= E.StartDateTime
       LEFT OUTER JOIN AppointmentResults AR( NOLOCK )
                    ON AR.EventId = E.Id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LeadSources LS( NOLOCK )
                    ON LS.Id = L.LeadSourceId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LeadTypes LT( NOLOCK )
                    ON LT.Id = L.LeadTypeId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Users EM( NOLOCK )
                    ON EM.Id = E.EmployeeId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Zone Z( NOLOCK )
                    ON Z.Id = C.ZoneId
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM   WorkflowStatus WS( NOLOCK )
              WHERE  TableId = 1
                     AND TableRowId = A.Id
                     AND WorkflowPhaseId = 9
                     AND IsCompleted = 0
                     AND IsDeleted = 0)
       AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM   dbo.Uft_userpermissionzonesbyworkflow(@EmployeeId, 9)
                     WHERE  ZoneId = C.zoneid) )
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Uft_userenableddealers(@EmployeeId)
                   WHERE  DealerId = C.DealerId)
ORDER  BY C.LastName,
          C.CompanyName,
          C.CompanyContact
```

I already tuned up to my knowledge but still I can see some index scans. I tried to convert those index scans to index seek but it is not possible due to number of records.

Please refer the screenshot of plan diagram and top operations
Kindly provide any suggestions to improvise this query.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @p TABLE (DealerId INT PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON))
INSERT INTO @p
SELECT DealerId
FROM dbo.Uft_userenableddealers(@EmployeeId)

DECLARE @z TABLE (ZoneId INT PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON))
INSERT INTO @z
SELECT ZoneId
FROM dbo.Uft_userpermissionzonesbyworkflow(@EmployeeId, 9)

SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM   WorkflowStatus WS( NOLOCK )
              WHERE  TableId = 1
                     AND TableRowId = A.Id
                     AND WorkflowPhaseId = 9
                     AND IsCompleted = 0
                     AND IsDeleted = 0)
       AND C.zoneid IN (SELECT * FROM @z)
       AND C.DealerId IN (SELECT * FROM @p)
ORDER  BY C.LastName,
          C.CompanyName,
          C.CompanyContact
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Would you think there is an improvement, if you'd have your declared tables as CTE?

Comment: @VR46, for tables only with one column this syntax is correct

Comment: @Shnugo, maybe OP just try it and provide results?

Comment: @Devart - Yeah I see that.

Comment: @Devart: Now most of the index scans turned to Index seeks. I can see some gain now.Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: @NewUser, would you please do me the favor and test this converting the declared tables into CTEs? Thx

Comment: Actually I joined the table variables instead of writing inside IN clause. Will the CTE perform better than table variable approach.

Comment: Please give me a sample example using CTE

Comment: upvote from my side as I coudl gain some rep points driving behind you :-)

Comment: do the same ;) but the way before I didn't know that CTE is ad-hoc. thanks

Comment: @Devart, One more hint in this direction: CTEs are very often the key to create an inlineable (ad-hoc) UDF. In my daily work I see many multi-statement SPs ans UDFs where the first statements are nothing more than some variable declares. Shuffling this into a CTE can speed up things enormously...Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

as discussed below Devarts answer here the example with a CTE instead of the declared table variables. I'd assume that the declared TVs are faster due to the key, but the CTE is ad-hoc and - maybe - better integrated. Thx for testing:

```
;WITH p AS
(
    SELECT DealerId
    FROM dbo.Uft_userenableddealers(@EmployeeId)
)
,z AS
(
    SELECT ZoneId
    FROM dbo.Uft_userpermissionzonesbyworkflow(@EmployeeId, 9)
)
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM   WorkflowStatus WS( NOLOCK )
              WHERE  TableId = 1
                     AND TableRowId = A.Id
                     AND WorkflowPhaseId = 9
                     AND IsCompleted = 0
                     AND IsDeleted = 0)
       AND C.zoneid IN (SELECT ZoneId FROM z)
       AND C.DealerId IN (SELECT DealerId FROM p)
ORDER  BY C.LastName,
          C.CompanyName,
          C.CompanyContact
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can see 6 index scans when I change like this. Both answers are almost gives the same time. In either case I can see some sort of improvement. Table variable approach has less index scans.

Comment: @NewUser, Thank you! And what's about the pure performance (running time)?

Comment: @NewUser, sorry, missed your edit... Might be, that some of the index-scans are hidden in the "declared TV" approach as they happen when you fill the TVs. Maybe you should measure the filling separately... UDFs tend to take much, if they are not optimal in design...

Comment: I am wondering since my actual query itself took around 5 secs after running multiple times. Table variable approach -3secs CTE between 3-5 secs.

Comment: @NewUser, "running multiple times" could mean, that SQL Server can use cached results, this may be an unrealistic picture... Test with different input parameters

Comment: Devart and Shnugo: Thank you so much for your help. I can see some improvement now. I don't know how to select both the answers.

Comment: @NewUser, You can upvote both, but please select Devart's answer as accepted. He did the big work :-)